# How to Read JSON Date in R

Tags: r, json, date

I want to read this date 1199145600000, which is saved in JSON, in R.

to convert the numerical representation of the date to a string
but when I type:

```
           as.Date(1199145600000,origin = "1904-01-01")
```

I get the following:

```
          "-5877641-06-23"
```

When I should be getting this date

```
          1 Jan 2008 00:00:00 GMT
```

I tried library(lubridate) still with no success.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Your time value is in milliseconds, so you'll need to divide it by 1000 to get it in seconds. Then you can use `as.POSIXct()` to convert to a datetime

```r
as.POSIXct(1199145600000/1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")

# [1] "2008-01-01 GMT"
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This makes sense.